# How to abort Fastlane Scan tests when first UITest fails

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane, fastlane-scan

Basically what I need is to stop the UITests when the first one fails. 
I'm using Jenkins with Fastlane Scan.

I have the option to continue after failure disabled (but it only prevents this specific test to continue):

```
override func setUp() {
...        
    continueAfterFailure = false
...
}
```

My scan file contains the option to "fail_build" true.

But it keeps running even when the first on fails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continueAfterFailure` means that the current test does not continue after a failure, but the test *run* will continue onto the next test.

If you want tests to stop after a single failure, you can observe the failure state of the test in `tearDown()` and throw a fatal error to abort the run.

```
override func tearDown() {
  super.tearDown()
  if !testRun?.hasSucceeded {
    fatalError()
  }
}
```

Comment: `hasSucceeded` didn't work for me. Checking for `totalFailureCount` worked though.

Comment: @MartinDinh is correct. `hasSucceeded` wont work with multiple tests, as its value is only accurate at the end of a test run.